# How to show a login modal in Rails if a user tries to access an authorized section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, modal-dialog, devise, cancan

How would you implement a modal window saying "In order you to access this area you have to be logged in.." in combination with a login form below it every time a user tries to access authorized content.
I'm using **Rails 3, Devise and CanCan**.

My first thoughts were do put it somewhere in the application_controller.rb:

```
# application_controller.rb
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  flash[:error] = "Access denied."
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using a modal window, but this works

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    unless anybody_signed_in?
      authenticate_user!
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Access denied."
      redirect_to root_url
    end
 end
```

It will redirect the use to the login form. When the user provides his credentials, he'll be shown the page he wanted to access.